# Blue Prism - Write error in text field SAP SPY MODE

Tags: rpa, blueprism, sap-gui

**Can't write or navigate into a spyed element with SAP SPY MODE.**

When I try to write an internal error pops up. In my opinion it is caused by SAP due to some security restrictions or permissions but I'm not an SAP specalist so I don't know what to change.

I also tried by using region mode and enter the text by Global Send Keys/Event but that also doesn't work.

Already tried:

- Spy with all modes (only SAP Spy mode works for text fields)
- Write to text field or navigate
- Region mode selection and write with global send keys/event

This sends text like àààààéàà instead of the right value    Checked with just the text "11111" or by sendig it through a variable

- Use keys like tab to get to the right textfield and put in text

[Screenshots of BluePrism Setup and error:

1. [image: BP_Sap spy mode setup]
2. [image: BP RM mode error]
3. [image: Interal error write]

Error message on 3th image:
The purpose of a call has caused an exception

Comment: Nobody who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if you have SAP scripting enabled?

Please refer to the section "Enabling SAP GUI Scripting on the Client Side" at this [link.](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/enabling-sap-gui-scripting)

Comment: Sorry forget to mention it:

SAP Scripting on client and server side are ok. 
Accessibility is also on.

Already checked that a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Even though everything was working out just fine in the interactive machine, tests on runtime environments were unsuccessful.

I solved it by:

**-** navigating through 'send keys' {TAB}

**-** after landing in the cell I was looking for, 'send keys' {BS} (somehow it allowed me to write there)

**-** writing from a 'data item' through 'send keys' again

Hope it helps!